# How to use QT signals and slots in QGIS C++ API

Tags: c++, qt, qgis

I'm developing a standalone QT 5.11.2 application using QGIS 3.6 C++ API.

I have defined a slot that is meant to consume a `currentLayerChanged(QgsMapLayer * layer)` signal.

The slot declaration in the header file is:

```
private slots:
    void on_CurrentLayer_changed(QgsMapLayer *layer);
```

The slot definition is:

```
void MainWindow::on_CurrentLayer_changed(QgsMapLayer *  layer)
{
    // do something here
}
```

When I try to build I get a linker error:

```
moc_mainwindow.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: símbolo externo "public: static struct QMetaObject const QgsMapLayer::staticMetaObject" (?staticMetaObject@QgsMapLayer@@2UQMetaObject@@B) sin resolver al que se hace referencia en la función "int __cdecl qRegisterMetaType<class QgsMapLayer *>(char const *,class QgsMapLayer * *,enum QtPrivate::MetaTypeDefinedHelper<class QgsMapLayer *,1>::DefinedType)" (??$qRegisterMetaType@PEAVQgsMapLayer@@@@YAHPEBDPEAPEAVQgsMapLayer@@W4DefinedType@?$MetaTypeDefinedHelper@PEAVQgsMapLayer@@$00@QtPrivate@@@Z)
File not found: moc_mainwindow.obj
error: LNK1120: 1 externos sin resolver
```

Should I subclass any of the classes that emit the signal  `currentLayerChanged(QgsMapLayer * layer)` to define the slot?

Comment: Seems like you didn't compiled the header with the Qt Meta Object Compile (MOC) ? If not so maybe the `Q_OBJECT` macro is missing.

Comment: Do I have to compile the header? Doesn't Qt handle this automatically?
The `Q_OBJECT` macro is included in the header file. Is a regular `MainWindow` class.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem. In my case I just use another signal slot structure. I mean instead of using:

```
connect(sender,&className::signalName,receiver,slotName)
```

use this:

```
connect(sender,SIGNAL(signalName),receiver,SLOT(slotName))
```

It worked for me.